# Xcode Framework resources handling

Tags: iphone, xcode, frameworks, resources

I am a newbie to Xcode Framework. Had just make a bundle to be used as framework in other projects. My question is: How to make the resources exp: .xib, images usable by other project? I've tried copy bundle resources in build phases, but i dont know how to retrieve them.

Comment: what do you mean by retrieving them? are you not able to use them when they are appearing in bundle resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of tricky.  I've relied on some excellent work by Karl Stenerud [found here](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework).

Answer (score 0):

for adding resources (xib and images) copy them to project folder and drag and drop in Xcode project > supporting files (or any folder you have created ) and in pop up window check copy items into destination group and also check add to target..

then you can find these resources copied in Build Phase > copy bundle resources

**Edit** ! do you mean to ask something like this : where to find [these images of Facebook framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxDTi.png)  in your project? and are you saying they are not found in copy bundle resources?

Comment: how to find the resources in the project which import the framework?

Comment: @paperclipz please elaborate.. im not getting what you are asking for